# Help, have i bricked my Seagate 1TB SSHD?

Tags: system-installation

I've been a Windoze user for years but i've been getting increasingly annoyed with the bloat, especially after the recent free Windows 10 upgrade. So i thought it was time to choose an alternative operating system, namely Elementary.
I decided to setup my system as a dual boot, so i could test elementary alongside my Windows 10 installation. My hard disk is a Seagate 1TB SSHD (hybrid) and only contained two partitions, C: for Windows and S: for Storage. I had 50gb of unallocated space, which is where i wanted to install Elementary using the following guide http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-elementary-loki-usb-dual-boot/

Once i was in the Elementary installer, i entered my name and location and proceeded to scan for partitions. At this point i got a pop up box telling me something about incompatible partitions, UEFI and non GPT discs, i can't exactly remember. The installer advised me not to proceed (i had no intention of proceeding after that warning anyway, if i don't know what it means, then best left alone is my motto). So i clicked cancel in the installer and my PC restarted, but wouldn't boot to windows 10, just a black screen with a blinking cursor.
I installed a second old sata HD with a temporary install of Windos on, just so i could get into Administrative Tools to viw the partition. The screenshot below is the result.

[image: [2]]

Disk 0 is my 1TB SSHD and Disk 1 is my temporary windows install which is allowing me to type this.
I cant understand why disk 0 is showing as 487mb and 931gb partitions, as when it was working ffine i think my C partition was 100gb and my S partition was about800 gb. Maybe it was the previous 'system reserved' partition ?
Anyway, i'd like to know if it's possible to restore the partitions and get Windows booting again ? I'm going to be very annoyed if the hard drive is brink just because i filled in my name and location in the Elementary installer and then clicked cancel after the warning.
Please help, i'm desperate !

Comment: Do you have windows 10 install disk? you could try using the recovery option. maybe your windows boot manger has been messed up. The drive never had a efi partition like disk 1? Maybe it was MBR... I'd be very surprised if you bricked it. Worst case scenario is probably that it would have to be reformatted and windows reinstalled. I'm not sure if that's necessary. I've not used windows much and don't know what tools are out there on the windows side of things. Try the windows recovery, if you have an install disk, if that doesn't help, hopefully someone with more windows experience can help.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Michael. I tried using Windows Recovery from a usb stick several times, but startup repair fails each time. A friend installed Windows 7 years ago, and i did the free upgrade. I'm not sure how he set up my partitions, i know nothing about UEFI's, GPT's, or MBR's sorry, i'm a disabled pensioner with only a little BIOS knowledge. Please tell me if theres anything else i could try ?